# Why I failed to connect to the django server?

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu

I'm following a tutorial, using this command in a Docker container to start the Django server:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

[image]

But I can not connect to it by IP.

I am sure that I have already open the 8000 port and this port is on listening. By the way, I use the ubuntu and set the server in the aliyun.

Comment: Use the IP of the container.

Comment: Try `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser

Comment: Plz share your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: thanks for all, I test many methods include yours, finally I find I can connect by 4g but can not by WiFi, what the hell? In fact this question is not solved until now.

Answer (score 0):

At First Django works on port 8000 not on 8080. So you should use python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000. You can eazly kill port in linux server by type: `fuser 8080/tcp`

Comment: sorry, It's my mistake.  Actually I use the 8000 Port , I am going to fix it now.